# How to make a For Loop using mutate() function

Tags: r, for-loop

I am trying to index multiple columns of data and do not want to have multiple lines of code running.

Example:

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  A= c(245, 1124, 1256),
  B= c(548, 1145, 1248),
  C = c(234, 1348, 1594),
  D = c(231, 1124, 1354),
  E = c(354, 1784, 1942)
)

library(tidyverse)

list <- c(A, B, C, D, E)

df2 <- df1 %>%
 mutate(A = A/A[1]-1) %>%
 mutate(B = B/B[1]-1) %>%
 mutate(C = C/C[1]-1) %>%
 ... %>%
 ...
```

Unlike the example above, I have over 10 columns and over 100 rows of data, and I need to index to the 11th row and want to try using a 'for loop' to help me do this. I am very new to for loops so I am trying to learn the best way to get this done.

This is what I've tried:

```
for (list in df1) {
 mutate(df1, list = list/list[1]-1)
}
```

I have also seen other threads recommending to use `mutate_()`, but I am not sure what the difference is.

Any help will be appreciated - my first question on Stack Overflow!

Comment: Can you show what the expected result would be using your 3x5 example data?

Comment: I'm guessing you want `df1 %>% mutate(across(A:E, ~.x/first(.x)-1))`. That will do all the column transformations in one go. No need for a loop

Comment: mutate() is used instead of a for loop. mutate goes through every row of data and performs some action on it. If you want to reference different rows in a mutate you can check out `first`, `last`, `lag`, `lead`, or other similar functions from the dplyr package.